# Apache Storm tuple timeout questions

Tags: apache-storm

I'm trying to understand the state of the topology in case of tuple processing timeout (not in Trident mode)
Lets assume that during a processing of a tuple in some bolt the timeout threshold was reached. In that case the spout emits the initial tuple again (with same message id as i understand). Now lets say the Bolt finishes  to process the tuple and emits and acks the tuple.
In that scenario :

1. Will the failed tuple still continue to be processed by the topology even though the spout emitted new one initial tuple ?
2. If so how  would the acker's DAG of tuples will look like (Since there is a new DAG created with same initial tuple id) what will happen to the previous original DAG?
3. what will happen when the acker receives ack and emit with anchor
   ids of the previous DAG ?

Answer (score 2):

1: Yes, the failed tuple continues. The reason for this is that it would be too expensive to try to stop the failed tuple from continuing, as the spout would need to tell all the bolts about the failure.

2: I think there's a small misunderstanding here. When the spout emits the tuple, the message id is not what Storm uses to track that tuple DAG/tree internally. Instead, the spout executor generates a random id (call it `rootId`), and locally stores the mapping of `rootId -> messageId`. The message id never leaves the spout executor, and isn't propagated to the bolts.

When the spout executor sends the tuple onward, it includes the `rootId`. The `rootId` is what is used by the acker and bolts to identify the tuple tree.

Finally when the tree is fully acked, or a tuple fails, the spout executor is told that the relevant `rootId` succeeded or failed, and it looks up the original `messageId` in its local mapping.

Since a new emit with the same `messageId` gets a new `rootId`, there is no relation between the failed and new tuples. They are considered completely separate by Storm.

I simplified the above a bit for clarity, in order to handle a spout emitting to multiple bolts, there's another set of random ids (`anchorId`) involved. Conceptually you can think the situation where you have

```
spout -> bolt1
      -> bolt2
```

as being handled as if the topology were

```
spout -> splitterBolt -> bolt1
                      -> bolt2
```

3: Let's say your tuple has timed out. The spout executor has been told that the `rootId` has failed. When that happens, the spout executor calls `spout.fail(msgId)`, and then deletes the mapping in the `rootId -> messageId` map.

When the acker receives the ack, it might send the ack on to the spout, if the tree is fully acked. When the spout receives the ack, it has nothing matching the `rootId` stored, so the ack is ignored.

If you're interested in taking a look at the code, it can be found at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/b48e10559b65e834884d59887b30fc86d2988c20/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/executor/spout/SpoutOutputCollectorImpl.java#L109. The `rootId -> messageId` mapping is called `pending`.